# Filtering perf stacks based on number of samples

Tags: text-processing, perf, flamegraph

After a `perf record` run, I can create a text file containing folded stacks via

```
perf script | ~/FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl > unprocessed_stacks.txt
```

In these `unprocessed_stacks.txt`, I might have a recursively called `[unknown]` function which is only sampled once, for example:

```
[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown];[unknown]; 1
```

When I construct a flamegraph out of this, I have a very thin peak which dominates the vertical scale but otherwise provides no insight into the data.

I would like to either 1) discard all folded stacks which comprise less than (say) 0.1% of the total samples recorded in the `perf.data`, or 2) put all of these low frequency stacks into a `[misc] N` bin.

This is a straightforward script to write in say `awk` or `python`, but is this already supported in the [Flamegraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) toolsuite or is it supported natively by `perf`?